# Color contrast ratio for highlighting color of selected item in <select>

Tags: accessibility, html-select, contrast, wcag, wcag2.0

WCAG requires that text color constrast should meet 4.5:1 ratio.

When you click an item on `<select>` it's usually highlighted with blue background color and white font color, something like this:

[image: HTML markup for and screenshot of select list; the selected option is highlighted with white text on a blue background]

And usually such highlighting does not meet that "4.5:1 rule" -- for example on my browser, such color highlighting's contrast ratio is 2.98:1.

How do you resolve such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a non fixed (but closed) bug in some browsers (Chrome for instance:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=398417)

Overriding `background-color` value for `option:checked` elements should work but it doesn't, *by design*.

But you can perfectly use `background-image` property:

```
select option:checked {
  background-image: url('accessible-blue.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am pasting another similar example (essentially same techniques with working example) here for future users who may have similar concern: https://www.speich.net/articles/en/2014/01/23/css-trick-setting-background-color-of-a-selected-html-option-element/